# Please explain this format code

Tags: python, format

What does the `{1}` represent in

```
print('{0:>{1}}'.format(num, width), end='')
```

I saw this code [here](http://pastebin.com/hPa1bb0V) for solving [this multiplication table problem](http://www.reddit.com/r/beginnerprojects/comments/2agwnq/project_multiplication_table/).

Comment: Maybe [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)?

Comment: can explain me more on this

Comment: Could please explain me more on this? thank you

Comment: You've read the whole thing already? That was quick! Could you be more specific about what it is that's confusing you? Have you tried running the code, and altering it to see what difference it makes? The parameters have sensible names, so it is pretty clear what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The {1} is referring to the width variable. In this case, it is part of the format spec for alignment width (padding).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec